# The constructor of Object.prototype

Tags: javascript, oop, prototypal-inheritance

In JavaScript, every object inherits its properties and methods from a specific prototype, where prototypes are objects.

The inheritance forms a prototype chain where (Object.prototype) stands at its top (followed by null which has no properties or methods) and all the objects inherit from it (unless someone else inserts other changes to the prototype chain).

If (Object.prototype) is an object, what is its constructor?

I mean what completes this expression in order to be evaluated to true.

```
Object.prototype instanceof .....
```

Comment: [It's turtles all the way down](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turtles_all_the_way_down)

Comment: There does not need to be a constructor, it is a built–in Object that just is. You might as well ask what is the constructor for *null*.

Comment: null is a primitive although using the typeof operator it evaluates to 'object'

Comment: That is not the case, it is important to know how javascript works behind the scenes in order to understand the objects and other things!

Comment: @YousefEssam—I don't know what you mean by "*that is not the case*". If it's created by a constructor function, then that function must already have *Object.prototype* on its `[[Prototype]]` chain. Where did that come from?

Comment: That what I mean. Prototypes are objects so Object.prototype is an object.
So what is its constructor? Of course, it can't be Object (whose prototype is Object.prototype) so care to explain if there is any misunderstanding?

Answer (score 1):

From ["this and Object Prototypes" book of "You don't know JS"](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/README.md) series by Kyle Simpsion

```
function Foo() {
    // ...
}

Foo.prototype.constructor === Foo; // true

var a = new Foo();
a.constructor === Foo; // true
```

> The `Foo.prototype` object by default (at declaration time on line 1 of
>   the snippet!) gets a public, non-enumerable (see Chapter 3) property
>   called `.constructor`, and this property is a reference back to the
>   function (Foo in this case) that the object is associated with.
>   Moreover, we see that object `a` created by the "constructor" call `new  Foo()` seems to also have a property on it called `.constructor` which
>   similarly points to "the function which created it".
>
> Note: This is not actually true. a has no `.constructor` property on it,
>   and though `a.constructor` does in fact resolve to the `Foo` function,
>   "constructor" does not actually mean "was constructed by", as it
>   appears. We'll explain this strangeness shortly.
>
> ...
>
> "Objects in JavaScript have an internal property, denoted in the
>   specification as [[Prototype]], which is simply a reference to another
>   object.".

So, Object.prototype itself is not an object. As to your specific question about instanceof:

```
var a = new Function();
a.prototype instanceof Object; //true
var b = new String();
b.prototype instanceof Object; //false
```

Comment: Ok, I don't talk about the constructor property now. I ask what the function constructor that was used to create the instance (Object.prototype) is.

Comment: In the example you showed, the constructor function that created the instance a is Foo. Similarly, what is the constructor that created Object.prototype?

Comment: Edited. See if this clarifies things.

Comment: The prototype property can be only accessed through constructor functions, so if you want to access the prototype of b you use __ proto __ not prototype so b.__proto__ instanceof Object will actually return true!

Comment: `__proto__` is a shorthand for `Object.getPrototypeOf()`. What b.__proto__ doing is creating an object out of the b.prototype reference. So, if you do 
`b.__proto__ instanceof Object`


 you are creating an Object and then checking it against `instanceof Object` - naturally, it returns true.